# How to correctly synchronize vector between classes to avoid using static?

Tags: java, string, vector, static

I have a class that reads a vector of vectors, this even contains a String name and the internal vector that has "bets" from players.

However, I am using static in the reading vector, if I remove the word static, when in the comparison class the vector is always zeros. (I understand that I am giving a new object in the comparison class and it is not associated with the vector that was previously populated)

I would like to change the code to synchronize the vectors between 3 classes so that I could do the correct parameter passing but I don't know how to do it.

Could you please explain to me how to synchronize the vector between classes correctly?

Remembering that it is not just the vector, they are bet-type objects composed of string name + vector of bets.

This Class readTemplate has a static declaration:
**public static int[] templateVector= new int [13];**

CLASS readTemplate - part of code:

```
public void readTemplate() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        
    File templatesFile= new File ("C:\\Temp\\templatesFile.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(templatesFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        
    String row;
        
    int j = 0;
        
    while((row= br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] strings = row.split(" ");
        for (String str : strings) {
             Integer foo = Integer.parseInt(str);
             templatevector[j] = foo;
             j++;
        }       
    }
        
    br.close();
    fr.close();
}
```

part of the code, for understanding purposes only:

Class generateResults (compare this template file with bets to find winner)

```
public void generateResult() throws IOException {
    
    ReadTemplate Template = new ReadTemplate();
    ReadBets a = new ReadBets();
    
    File output = new File ("C:\\Temp\\output.txt");
    
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c:\\Temp\\output.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    
    bw.write("TEMPLATE READ:");
    for (int j = 0; j < template.vectorTemplate.length; j++) {
        bw.write(template.vectorTemplate[j] + " ");
    }
    
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write("+--Result Bets:--+");
    bw.newLine();
    
    try {
        if (!output.exists()) {

        output.createNewFile();
    }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;
    
        for(int x = 0; x < template.vectorTemplate.length; x++) {
            if (a.totalStakes[j].vectorStakes[i] == template.vectorTemplate[x]) {
                counter++;
            }
        i++;
    }
}
```

thank you very much to anyone who takes the time to explain to me.

Comment: wy not create an object that contains a name and a list of bets for each player, instead of dealing with nested vector. Java is object oriented, use objects, use the type system. Also when you read the template, why arn\t you returning the vector from the function? stop using void functions, and start using return types

Comment: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)